iPhone 12 Pro showing weak sensitivity when doing “very gentle” tap/touch. What could be the issue?
I bought a refurbished iPhone 12 Pro yesterday, from a third party mobile shop. Since the first day, the screen does not recognise touch when I tap “very gently”. For example, when I am tapping any icon (or key) “very gently”, the touch is not recognised. I have to do proper touch always.
I used iPhone (iPhone 13 brand new) before in my life during 2023 and I never faced this. The screen was very sensitive to even very tiny/mild touch.
What could be the issue with my current refurbished iPhone 12 Pro? (I live in Portugal, the shop is in Portugal as well. iOS version 17.4.1)

If it doesn't work as expected, why not just bring it back and demand a refund?

Yes I am gonna do that. But do you think it’s a hardware or software problem?

I have no idea, these issues are hard to analyse without access to the device itself. But if 17.4.1 would have a touch issue, it probably would be widely known already.

What options do I have to resolve this now?

Take it back and have it replaced/fixed.

If the same problem still persists after fix or replacement, then?

Ask for your money back? Live with it? Not sure what kind of help we can give on this.

Can I be sure that if the screen is replaced with a genuine Apple part (from apple Authorized repair shop), the touch problem will go away?

If you get a proper job done at an Apple store then yes it should work properly (as you would expect), but they might charge you so much that it isn't worth it. It is unlikely to still be under warranty, especially as you didn't buy it from them. But it would not hurt to go and ask. However, I would just go back to where you bought it from and try to get your money back, or it fixed for free, first of all.

You can be pretty sure that it is a hardware issue - with the screen itself. It is unlikely to be an issue with the main board.
If it was refurbished by a third party shop then it is almost certain to have a cheap screen replacement, one that doesn't live up to Apple's standard - that is to say a substandard part that either failed testing, or was manufactured by a "clone" factory, that doesn't have the same stringent standard of quality control.
Generally, these "fake" parts will be as good as the "official" parts (or good enough that you don't notice any defect), but now and again you will get a duff one, that doesn't quite cut the mustard, so to speak.
I have seen this quite a few times, either on screens that I have replaced myself, with parts from eBay, or if I got a cheap replacement done at one of the plethora of mobile phone repair shops in malls in Thailand. Usually, things work out fine, but very roughly speaking, maybe 10-20% replacement screens have defects, such as substandard touch capabilities, or there are bright spots (or dark lines) on the screen.
Usually, if the issue really is something that you can not live with, you can go back to the shop and point out the issue. They will either say "Well, what did you expect?" or, if they are one of the better shops and are proud of their work, they will endeavour to replace the screen (maybe free of charge, maybe for a small fee), with one of slightly better quality.
As always, "you get what you pay for"... this time you weren't particularly lucky,

I forgot to mention one thing, they also installed a glass screen protector. Do you think the weak responsiveness can happen due to that?

Capacitive touch should allow glass protector to be normal thickness and still operate. Since the screen isn’t feeling the force of your touch, it’s probably poor quality in the “touch screen” and needs a second repair. I would ask them to remove the protector and retest with other ones and then you’ll have to decide if it’s worth it to keep @Natal

Will they allow me to return this phone and give a full refund?

@bmike - That is a good point about the screen protector... it could be due to that. Unrelated but I once made a fool of myself by going back to the shop saying that the ear phone speaker had broken during the repair, and that the sound was really quiet. It turned out that the film hadn't been removed and was blocking the tiny hole..!

@Natal - Refund? No idea. It depends upon EU customer rights and what mood the shop owner is in. And how assertive you are. Also act fast. If you bought it yesterday then hopefully they should, but they can say that once you've left the shop, you could have damaged it (if they want to be particularly difficult)...
